# Computation of DFA states

Tags: regex, lex, flex-lexer

I want to compute the total number of DFA states for a certain regular expression using FLEX. Which C files or functions will help me to achieve this task using FLEX?

Comment: I don't think that lex/flex can help you here, but perhaps there are other C-language tools that can analyze your regex for you.

Comment: @DavidGorsline Can you please suggest me the name of those C language tools that can compute the number of DFA states for each RE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the file generated by `flex`, then the number of entries in `yy_accept` (and `yy_base`) will probably give a good indication of the number of states used by the generated DFA. If you'd use `-Cf` option then `yy_nxt` contains the transition function of the DFA and the number of rows in the table is again the number of used states.

You may have a different version of `flex` where the tables are named differently, but most likely their names will be very similar.

In reaction to your questions below: the number of states in a DFA could be considered quite well defined, assuming the DFA has been minimized. The number of transitions is however much less well defined.

In the first place `flex` has a transition for each input character as it will `ECHO` any character that is not part of the defined language. This is implemented by a fresh new state to handle that case. Using a debugger you could reverse engineer which state this is. But beware that if you use start conditions, you may have to consider the possibility that there are multiple such states. If you want to analyze many regular expressions, then you may want to look into some other tools or take the sources of `flex` and go from there.

In the second place `flex` has strategies to minimize the total size of all the tables. The `-Cf` option instructs it to not do that. One such optimization is finding equivalence classes of characters and only use transitions for each character class. An input character is first translated to its class, which in turn is used to determine the transition. As a consequence the number of transitions is much lower, but an additional table (see `yy_ec`) is required for determining the character class.

As a consequence the *number of transitions* is a not so well defined concept. If you are interested in determining the memory footprint of the scanner, then I would look at the size of the data section of the scanner. Use for example `objdump -h` on the `lex.yy.o` file. The size of the `.rodata` section will give a quite accurate estimate of the total size of the tables.

You seemed to have already found the `-v` option of `flex` that gives the number of states in the DFA in a more verbose form. In answer to why `"a" {}` gives 5 states, you may also use the `--trace` option as it gives the DFA while it is generated. Apparently there is also an `End Marker` rule, I assume it is used for end-of-file. For each start condition there are two states, one that is used when at the start of a line and one in the middle of a line. That makes 3 accepting states (one for `"a"`, one for `End Marker` and one for `(.|"\n")`) plus two states for the single start condition.

The source file `dfa.c` is not part of the generated code, but if you feel brave you could of course change the sources of `flex` to do further analysis of your own. I had a quick look and it does seem that generation of the code is intertwined with the transformations, which makes it a bit less modular than one would desire for an experimentation platform. Also beware of the K&R prototypes which effectively disables any type checking on the prototypes.

Comment: Can you please further elaborate this? Actually, I want to find out two more things like total number of transitions and the storage size of these transition tables.How can i find out these things using flex?

Comment: @Zara I've elaborated a bit more, but there is no clear cut answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: yy_accept gives high number of DFA states like for a RE of ab, there should be just two states but it gives more than 5.I don't get it why is it happening..

Comment: Secondly, how can I make use of file dfa.c of flex? Are the functions of dfa.c  used in lex.yy.c?

Comment: @Zara Beware that `flex` always adds the implicit rule `(.|"\n") {ECHO;}` which will add states. We are clearly working with different versions of `flex`, because `"ab" {}` gives me 7 states (with `-Cf`, otherwise 8) and my `flex` doesn't generate a `dfa.c`, so I can't answer the last question. Actually `"ab" {}` has at least 3 states.

Comment: Okay, actually I am using version 2.5.37 and this dfa.c is present in the folder flex-2.5.37. In my case also, only lex.yy.c is generated but actually I was curious to know where would this dfa.c would be used between thanks for the help .

Comment: One more question in my version of flex, I have used the option full and when I print the statistics I get 5 dfa states for the RE ,"a". Can u please elaborate how 5 states? Echo state is just one in number?

Comment: @Zara I had a quick look at the sources of 2.5.37 and added an attempt to answer above.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot. One more thing ,I tried to use %option trace in my .l file but that gives me error, I don't know why. Secondly , In verbose statistics two more things appear unique/duplicate transitions. Do they refer to the number of transitions of DFA? Last, how can I print just the dfa states and these unqiue transitions to a text file?

Comment: @Zara `--trace` is a command line option. I'd use `sed` or `grep` (or a combination) on the output of `flex -v` to extract the desired figures.